# How to uninstall / remove tiller from Kubernetes manually?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've by mistake installed an unsecured configuration of tiller.

I've tried `helm reset` but something must have corrupted because now when I try to install helm:

```
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/chris/.helm.
Warning: Tiller is already installed in the cluster.
(Use --client-only to suppress this message, or --upgrade to upgrade Tiller to the current version.)
Happy Helming!
```

However if I try `helm ls` I get:

`Error: could not find tiller`.

So because helm reset is insufficient, or there is some bugs, which resources do I need to delete in order to be able to reinstall helm correctly (`helm init`)?

Answer (score 11):

Tiller can be uninstalled using the command

```
helm reset --force
```

or

```
helm reset --force --wait
```

It will force the clean of all resources inside the cluster. With that you are able to run `helm init` again.

Answer (score 10):

```
kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy -n k8s-tiller
kubectl delete service tiller-deploy -n k8s-tiller
kubectl delete -n=k8s-tiller rs tiller-deploy-6f65cf89
```

Initially I ran init with the --namespace set as `k8s-tiller`

This also might be useful:

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces | grep tiller
```

Comment: removing of `rs` not necessary

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you looking for:

Remove all sensitive info created for tiller:

```
kubectl get -n kube-system secrets,sa,clusterrolebinding -o name|grep tiller|xargs kubectl -n kube-system delete
kubectl get all -n kube-system -l app=helm -o name|xargs kubectl delete -n kube-system
```

First command remove all senstive info that might be left for behind, and the last one removes all workloads (pods,services,deployments,replicasets) filtering by the label `app=helm`

Comment: The first command is not a very safe command to be re running...  It is helpful none the less.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SSL between Helm and Tiller](https://helm.sh/docs/tiller_ssl/), so this worked for me:

```
kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy -n kube-system
kubectl delete service tiller-deploy -n kube-system
kubectl delete secret tiller-secret -n kube-system
```

If you don't delete the secret, you get the "Tiller is already installed on this cluster" error and the certs are not updated (which makes Helm hang).