# Is `helm reset --force` meant to be executed once per physical host or once per cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

From this question [How to uninstall / remove tiller from Kubernetes manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612553/how-to-uninstall-remove-tiller-from-kubernetes-manually) I see I can use

```
helm reset --force
```

to quoting https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-reset ...

> uninstalls Tiller (the Helm server-side component) from your Kubernetes Cluster and optionally deletes local configuration in $HELM-HOME (default ~/.helm/)

My question is :

In a multi-node cluster should this be ran once per master or once per cluster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once per cluster should be enough, because tiller is a single cluster-wide component that is running completely on kubernetes, not tied to a specific node.

Additionally, you do not need to run this command on the nodes themselves - you can run it locally as well, as long as you can talk to the kube-apiserver. This is what is meant by the "local configuration files (`~/.helm.`)".

Comment: Thank you. So in a multi-master cluster, would one typically install the helm binary on each node, and later when uninstalling clean up *once per cluster* via e.g. `/usr/local/bin/helm reset --force && kubectl delete serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller && kubectl delete clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule` and *once per host* for deleting the installed files like  /usr/local/bin/helm and ~/.helm etc.

Comment: You don’t need to install the helm binary to the nodes at all. You can have it only locally. Nodes do not need it. And you can do the reset from your local machine, while targeting the cluster (your *context* that is in your kubeconfig file should be looking to your cluster). Same with clusterroles and bindings - all of these (helm resources, cluster role and binding) live in the cluster, and they have nothing to do with the nodes. You delete them only once. In fact, typically, after the cluster is once set up, you don’t do anything on the nodes, or “per node”.

Comment: Thank you Utku. Yes I am get that helm client can run anywhere.  I probably should have clarified I'm using ansible to run the helm binary and it is executing on the hosts(s) themselves but when running kubectl command it is hitting potentially a different master.
Rather than have an install of `helm` on my ansible client (e.g. my laptop) , I'm considering installing helm on the hosts (or more specifically on all the hosts in case later when I  uninstall via ansible one of the hosts is no longer reachable). 
Hopefully this is not a crazy approach :-)

Comment: @k1eran That's completely fine approach, and in fact, I do exactly the same myself (ansible, install helm binary to the node itself). So, in this case, you can still run `helm reset` and `kubectl delete` commands only from one master - all commands that involve `helm` or `kubectl` are run *on kubernetes*  and are cluster-wide operations - don't need to be done per-node.